# How to write meta-data info to Android Manifest at runtime

Tags: android, android-manifest

I know its possible to edit a android manifest component, for example, set it enabled/disabled etc. I'd like to insert meta value tag into the application tag of the android manifest at runtime.  How can i write directly into the android manifest ?

here is the string i want to write directly into my app's android manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="my_api_key" android:value="mykey124" />
```

and it must be within the application tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't edit the manifest at runtime.

If you need runtime solution, you should try other ways like share preference or something can save value persist.

If not just put it in manifest, take google play service for Example:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    .....
</application>
```

Comment: Why can't you store in other place?

Comment: I want to change meta value after it passes google review

Comment: Tell me how to change

Comment: I think you can use share preference as alternative. 
Read meta value as the default preference value and change the preference when you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think its late, but will help for any other searching for this answer

**first**
Go to res > values > strings.xml and create the string resource

```
 <string name="my_api_key">Your_api_key</string>
```

and After that Go to **manifest** file

Be sure you want to add this meta tag in your application or activity
if You want to add inside the application then just start after the application tag or if activity the after the activity tag on which you want to write

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="apikey"
            android:value="@string/my_api_key" />
```

Now finally its time to retrieve the meta data inserted in the application or the activity,

```
 try {
        ActivityInfo ai = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
        if (bundle != null) {
            String apiKey = bundle.getString("apikey");
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "apiKey = " + apiKey);

            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Utilities.log(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

if you have put the metatag in the application then use

```
 ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

instead of Activity info , thats all.

Comment: I want to edit the meta data at runtime. Your showing how to read it

Comment: Did you achieve this, i mean change the metadata at runtime ? @j2emanue

Comment: No.  Seems very hard

Comment: There is no ways to edit manifest at run-time, but you can do this at build-time - while Gradle build system builds your project. This is the only place, when you can do this. When app already built, Manifest becomes as a constant