# Is it possible for an app to have more than one CastOptionsProvider, as a means to cast to 2 different Receiver Apps?

Tags: android, chromecast

Basically, I'm converting an application to a library module. The problem is that this application has Chromecast capability, and hence has its own `CastOptionsProvider` in the manifest, and the application that's going to use this library has its own `CastOptionsProvider`, leading to a manifest merger failure.

I know this is supposed to be a manifest merger problem, but this is more about the Chromecast part of the app. Is it possible for one app to have 2 `CastOptionsProvider`s to cast into 2 different Receiver Apps?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** You can declare an `OptionsProvider` class in your library, and if needed, your application can declare its own `OptionsProvider` class to use instead. **To switch between different receiver apps while your application is running, you should use the `CastContext.setReceiverApplicationId` method to override the settings from the `OptionsProvider`.**

**Background**

According to the [Chromecast codelab](http:///https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#4), `CastOptionsProvider` is a class you write yourself. You can actually call it anything you want, as long as it implements `com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OptionsProvider`. This also means that you could write more than one `CastOptionsProvider` class in the same app, as long as you put them in different packages or give them different names. You would declare each one of your `OptionsProvider`s like this:

```java
package your.pkg.goes.here;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OptionsProvider;
...

public class YourOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {...}

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {...}
}
```

So far, so good. Because you can call your `OptionsProvider` whatever you want, you also need to declare your `OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME` in the manifest so that the app knows how to get its cast options. That code belongs in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and it looks like this:

```xml
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
android:value="your.pkg.goes.here.YourOptionsProvider" />
```

Here is where it gets tricky. `meta-data` is for declaring key-value pairs, and [you can't have more than one value for the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665040/android-the-api-key-can-only-be-specified-once-meta-data-duplicates). You can have multiple `OptionsProvider` classes floating around in your code, that's fine, but only one of them can be used by the cast framework at a time. To change which one is used, you need to edit the manifest, which [you can't do while the app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577725/how-to-write-meta-data-info-to-android-manifest-at-runtime). The closest thing you can do is to have different builds of the app that use different `OptionsProvider`s.

**So which OptionProvider should I use?**

The behavior of an `OptionsProvider` is just defined by how it implements the functions, `getCastOptions` and `getAdditionalSessionProviders`. Figure out what behavior you need from your library, and write that behavior as library functions or classes that can be expanded on by your app. For example:

```java
package your.library;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OptionsProvider;
...

public class LibraryOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    public String YOUR_LIBRARY_APPLICATION_ID = "ASDFASDF";

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(YOUR_LIBRARY_APPLICATION_ID)
                // maybe set some other settings, too
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {...}
}
```

For an app that doesn't need special behavior, you can just put `LibraryOptionsProvider` in the app's manifest:

```xml
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
android:value="your.library.LibraryOptionsProvider" />
```

But for apps that need something special, you can declare your own `ApplicationOptionsProvider` that uses the `LibraryOptionsProvider` for some of its behavior.

```java
package your.application;

import your.library.LibraryOptionsProvider;
...

public class ApplicationOptionsProvider extends LibraryOptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id)) // use a different application ID from the one in LibraryOptionsProvider
                .build();
    }

    // inherit getAdditionalSessionProviders from LibraryOptionsProvider, no need to override it unless we want different behavior
}
```

Then your manifest should point to `ApplicationOptionsProvider` instead of `LibraryOptionsProvider`:

```xml
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
android:value="your.application.ApplicationOptionsProvider" />
```

**Summary so far:** It's up to the application to decide what behavior it needs from its `OptionsProvider`. If no special behavior is needed, the application should use an `OptionsProvider` that you declare in the library. When custom behavior is called for, such as when you need different cast options or a different cast application ID, then the application should declare its own `OptionsProvider`, which can depend on library code instead of re-implementing shared behavior.

**Multiple Application IDs**

The `OptionsProvider` is used to initialize the `CastOptions`, which is "a singleton class containing global context for the Cast SDK"([source](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext)). `CastContext` is initialized in the background when the app starts, but you can change the application ID whenever you want to, using `CastContext.setReceiverApplicationId(String applicationId)`. By doing so, you will ignore the receiver application ID that was configured in your `CastOptions`. **This is how you can switch between multiple receiver apps within a single build.**